# Comparing species size distribution across multiple habitats

Tags: distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am looking at one species' size distribution across three primary habitats, we'll call them Habitat A, B, and C for simplicity. I have taken multiple samples (seine tows) within each habitat (n varies between 9 and 30). Within each tow I collect between 0-300+ individual of the target species. What I want to do is compare the size distribution of this species across habitats A, B, and C to better understand whether there is some form of ontogenetic trend occurring between the habitats. I have used a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test in the past to test for difference between two different size distributions, but I'm unsure of how best to test whether there are differences among three size distributions.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, and without any data, I am not sure I'm clear
about your experimental design. In particular, for each observation,
is it the number of
individuals from the target species that matters? or is it their
proportion of all observed? (You only mention species counts as `0-300+`.)

So here are some Poisson data for three hypothetical sites, with
respective numbers of observations 9, 21, and 30.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rpois(9, 225)
x2 = rpois(21, 225)
x3 = rpois(30, 200)
x = c(x1,x2,x3)
g = rep(1:3, c(9,21, 30))
```

[If these data are not at all similar to what you have in mind, please
criticize them to give us a better idea of your experiment and goals.]

A boxplot of results shows target species counts from 174 to 216
among the 60 observations. Widths indicate relative group sample sizes.

```
boxplot(x~g, varwidth=T, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
mean(x1); mean(x2); mean(x3)
[1] 225.2222
[1] 229.6667
[1] 198.7
sd(x1); sd(x2); sd(x3)
[1] 9.947082
[1] 13.42138
[1] 13.62085
```

For Poisson data, the population variance *tends to increase* with the population
mean, so the equal-variance assumption of an ordinary ANOVA does not hold.
However, the Satterthwaite ANOVA implemented in the `oneway.test` procedure in R does not assume equal variances, and shows highly significant
differences among the three group means in my hypothetical data.

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 37.778, num df = 2.000, denom df = 25.323, p-value = 2.509e-08
```

*Ad hoc* tests using Welch 2-sample t tests (which also do not assume equal variances), show no difference between
groups 1 and 2 (P-value about 0.3), but do show that group 3 has significantly different
counts than does group 2. [An *ad hoc* test between group 1 and 3 is significant, but not shown. I would do these tests at the 1% level
to avoid false discovery, but the differences are highly significant
for my data.]

```
t.test(x1,x2)$p.val
[1] 0.3268518
t.test(x2,x3)$p.val
[1] 3.532091e-10
```